# location.href + specifying the search parameters

Tags: javascript, html, location-href

I am trying to load the url of a search page by specifying both the path I want to load and the search parameters that should be appended.

For example I'm loading /foo/?q=1&a=2
I would try to type something in javascript like this:

```
location.href = /foo/?q=1&a=2
```

Then when that's run I get an invalid token exception at the '&' character. I'm well versed in javascript and jquery so I'm open to an answer in either language.

I just need to be able to set location.href and it's associated search parameter so that I can load the page correctly. OR if you have suggestions as to other ways to do this I'm open to those as well.

Regards

Comment: `I'm well versed in javascript and jquery so I'm open to an answer in either language.`... jQuery is not a language. jQuery is a library written in javascript.

Comment: semantics; my intention was clear enough.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need your string in quotes like this:

```
location.href = "/foo/?q=1&a=2";
```

Javascript was probably interpreting `/foo/` as a regular expression and then trying to make sense of the other characters after it as options on the regex.

Comment: ahh, I should have realized that. Thanks!